# Two player game on a cube $100\times 100\times 100$

Tags: game-theory

The game:

Two players are playing a game on cube of size $100\times 100\times 100$ (Including zero). Starting the game, a coin is placed randomly on the square $\langle L,N,M\rangle$. Each player can reduce in his turn $1$ or $2$ from only one of the coordinate (and by that move the coin to the new square). The winner is the one that in his turn takes the coin to the square $\langle 0,0,0\rangle$.

The question is: if I want to be first or second, what should my strategy  be (what is the invariant condition)?

What I discoverd so far:

If one of the coordinates is zero, then my invariant condition is: after each turn of mine, the distance between the other two coordinates (that are not necessarily zero) is a multiple of $3$.
That is: if $\langle 0,N,M\rangle$ then the invariant condition is $|M-N|=3k$.

Edit 1: analysis of mine for several cases.

[image]

Comment: Does the dimension matters? I think it is the same as the same game on a line. The strategy should be to keep the manhattan distance between the coin and the origin is multiples of 3, that is $L+N+M = 3k$ after your move.

Comment: What if the coin ends up on $(1,0,0)$? You can't _not_ decrease any coordinate at your turn, it seems.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too. but for example (1,1,1) is winning situation, and so as (4,4,1) for example.

Comment: You *can* take 1 or 2 from each pile, or you *must* take 1 or 2 from each pile? Can you take nothing at all?

Comment: You know that it is safe to make a move that leaves (0,0,0), (0,1,1) and (0,2,2). It is also safe to leave any one of these with multiples of 3 added to the coordinates (prove this). If the coordinates are not of this form, is there always a move that brings it to this form?

Comment: It was not clear I'm sorry. I must choose one of the piles and take 1 or 2. Jaap do you mean that I can add multiply of 3 to one of the coordinated? Or that even if I put for example 2 in the first coordinate and 1 to the second it will be safe?

Comment: I mean that since (0,1,1) is safe to leave, so is (3a+0, 3b+1, 3c+1) for any non-negative integers a,b,c. Similarly for (0,0,0) and (0,2,2).

Comment: Thank you very much!